# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform While trying to connect to the Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am Trying to Connect to the Oracle 12c Database from my java with `JDBC` Drivers , I am using JDBC OCI layer when run my piece of code it gives the error as below 
I have tried with different dll files but facing same problem.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

> product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN`ocijdbc12.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll
>   on a AMD 64-bit platform
>         at java.lang.ClassLoaderNativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:4158)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:4154)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:453)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:60)
>         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>         at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)

Comment: make sure your java home and Oracle client are both 64 bit, or make a thin jdbc driver and bypass the client completely

Comment: You need to use a 32 bit JVM, or you need to install the 64 bit OCI client, or switch to the thin driver which doesn't have a native dependency.

Comment: Why use the Oracle JDBC-OCI when you can use the JDBC-thin driver which is more performant, supports more features and is 100% Java (type 4)?